# angularjs binding one attribute to another attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs:

Is it possible to bind the value 2 in the input_value attribute to the value in box-number?

```
<estimated-field input-value="boxes[2]" est-value="estimatedBoxes" box-number="2" />
```

In other words can you bind one attribute to another attribute?

Comment: Is this a directive? Is boxes[2] an expression?

Comment: yes, input-box is bound to $scope.boxes = [];

Comment: In your directive can do scope.inputValue=attr.boxNumber; in link function.